# Adding command to elastix dialplan

Tags: asterisk, elastix

TlDr: Is it possible to add a function (forkCDR) before Elastix Dial() an extension?

We had a working asterisk, but due to the administration is now transferred to a person with lesser competence, we have moved to another server with only Elastix GUI.

We had a forkCDR() before dial(), so our CRM-system could look in the CDR database to see current and terminated calls.

Without the forkCDR() in Elastix, the call is only logged after the call is terminated.

While the current admin thinks he can make an api to see only the current call; I'd rather have both current and terminated calls in the CDR, so the CRM does not have to make an api-call for current and a database lookup for past calls.

It is only nessecary on one extension, but what ever is easiest for the GUI-jockey will do ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The GUI restriction is a tough constraint.  The solution is trivial if you are prepared to add 2 lines of code to your dialplan (before the dial command in your dial macro, and upon hangup).  You may have to learn some dialplan basics, or hire someone who can do it for you.

Comment: I know how to write the dialplan, did the entire dialplan by hand. The problem is that I need to go the gui-jockey and say on which menu he is going to add the lines. It is the usual battle between GUI and CLI: GUI let's the stupid people do more than their abilities and smart people do less. Sorry for the sarcasm...